# HyperLink in XAML Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, hyperlink, windows-phone

Hi i am new Windows Phone XAML,i dont know how to use HyerLink

Here is My Code,

i need a HyerLink for the this Text,

```
  <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="120,160,0,0">
                <TextBlock  Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" >Where To Stay</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
```

but when i used the below code error occurs,

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="120,160,0,0">
                <TextBlock  Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" ><Hyperlink Click="Stay_Click">Where To Stay</Hyperlink></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
```

Please give me any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you simply use this,

```
<HyperlinkButton Width="Auto" Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" Click="Stay_Click">Where To Stay</HyperlinkButton>
```